# hammerjs pinch is eratic in ionic running on IOS13

Tags: ionic4, ios13

The pinch function from hammerjs 2.0.8 gives eratic values with IOS13 in an IONIC4 application.

The 'scale' values in the triggered events appear random and no longer in line with pinch movement. All works fine with IOS12.

I have added handling for the 'pinchcancel' event. Before I only handled 'pinchend', but with IOS13 one should also handle the cancel event. 
Without handing the cancel event the pinch operation will not be concluded. Handling the cancel event solves that, but not the eratic scale values.

```
<div #wrapper id="wrapper" (pinchstart)="onPinchStart($event)"
      (pinch)="onPinch($event)" (pinchend)="onPinchEnd($event)" (pinchcancel)="onPinchEnd($event)">
</div>
```

addition October 4th 2019:

Debugging showed that the onPinch handler receives events with eventType 8 that are way too high. I have for now added a test to skip eventType 8. That makes it better, but the pinch itselfs tends to end prematurely when one pinches somewhat rude or quickly.

Addition October 8th 2019:

Appearantly IOS 13 supports PointerEvents, but HammerJS does not handle these correct causing the eratic behaviour.
For now I have disable PointerEvents in HammerJS's code. That solves my problem.

Comment: Hi, my phone running 13.2.3 using ionic v3 also getting the random 'scale' value, Android works fine. After updating the original hammerjs with yours the problem still there. I dont think ionic version matters tho. Could be iOS 13.x.x?

Comment: It is caused by a change in IOS 13. It now supports pointerevents and hammer does not handle that properly. Pinches are cancelled unexpectedly. By disabling pointerevent handling in hammer the problem is avoided. Hammer is included in Ionic 3. Are you sure you are using my version there?

Comment: I ended up use the original hammerjs with the following options `let hammertime = new Hammer(elm, { touchAction: 'pan-y', inputClass: Hammer.TouchInput });` by specify hammerjs to allow vertical scroll on element and also use TouchInput only. My use case is to mimic the Instagram-like pinch-zoom-pan where image/videos are pan-able only during pinch event.